# Youtube API - Getting trending videos in a specific channel for time period

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

Today i have requirement in Youtube analytics API , Where i want to get trending/popular videos in particular channel, we have API Key for channel. Is there any api call to get top trending videos in channel?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Youtube Analytics Query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query) report specifying for the top 10 views video of your channel :

- dimensions : **video**
- max-results : **10**
- sort: **-views**

You can found a template [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DMINE&start-date=2010-01-01&end-date=2018-01-01&metrics=views%252Clikes%252Cdislikes&dimensions=video&max-results=10&sort=-views&_h=1&)

Answer (score 0):

There is no API call to get trending videos in a user's channel because how do you define "trending" in a programming sense? The word trend is not mentioned even once in the [Youtube Analytics and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics) docs.

But, you can get [views, likes and other metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics#likes) for a certain video.